# Как узнать ширину трансформированного изображения?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пользователь может изменять масштаб изображения колёсиком мышки, изменяя свойство transform:scale(), как получить ширину изображения после этого?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ширину/Высоту после любых трансформаций можно получить с помощью element.getBoundingClientRect().width/element.getBoundingClientRect().height